# Only select this if the first select is null

Tags: sql, select, refactoring, isnull

I have an sql select:

```
select t1.val1, t1.val2
  from table1 t1
 where t1.active = 1
   and t1.col1 =
       (select t2.col1
          from tabl2 t2
         where to_char(t2.id) = to_char('225'))
   and t1.col2 =
       (select t2.col2
          from tabl2 t2
         where to_char(t2.id) = to_char('225'))
  and t1.col3 = (
        select t4.col3
        from table2 t2, 
        table3 t3,
        table4 t4
        where to_char(t2.id) = to_char('225'))
        and t2.t1_id = t1.id
        and t2.t3_id = t3.id
        )
```

And if this whole select is null than i want to select this:

```
select t1.val1, t1.val2
  from table1 t1
 where t1.active = 1
   and t1.col1 =
       (select t2.col1
          from tabl2 t2
         where to_char(t2.id) = to_char('225'))
   and t1.col2 =
       (select t2.col2
          from tabl2 t2
         where to_char(t2.id) = to_char('225'))
  and t1.col3 is null
```

As it seems, the second select has only one differences t1.col3 is null, but i only want to make live this select if the first has no resultset...

Any idea appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use them both and run the second if the first one returns no rows.
But if you need to make one query try this using [WITH clause in Oracle.](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause.php) I guess you use Oracle?:

```
WITH T100 as
(
select t1.val1, t1.val2,t1.col3 
  from table1 t1
 where t1.active = 1
   and t1.col1 =
       (select t2.col1
          from tabl2 t2
         where to_char(t2.id) = to_char('225'))
   and t1.col2 =
       (select t2.col2
          from tabl2 t2
         where to_char(t2.id) = to_char('225'))
  and 
  (
   (t1.col3 = (
        select t4.col3
        from table2 t2, 
        table3 t3,
        table4 t4
        where to_char(t2.id) = to_char('225'))
        and t2.t1_id = t1.id
        and t2.t3_id = t3.id
        )
   ) 
   OR t1.col3 IS NULL 
  ) 
)

select val1, val2 
from T100 
where NVL(col3,XXXXXXXX) = NVL((select max(col3) from T100),XXXXXXXX)
```

Where XXXXXXXX is a unique value which can't exist in Col3 column.